# Is it possible to print multiple (and different) photos from Shotwell?

Tags: printing, shotwell, photo

I know how to print multiple instances of the same photo, but I need to print 4 different pictures on one sheet.

Does this functionality exist?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When in shotwell, highlight the images that you want to print, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click on the images that you want to print, and then click on File --> Print

[image]

Click on the Image Settings tab --> click on Autosize, choose the number of images per sheet, and then click print.

[image]

Comment: I have photos that are all in portrait view. I'd like to have 2 of them on a landscape page side by side. It puts them one above the other without a way of changing this. Any ideas?

Comment: There's no way to select multiple images in Ubuntu 20.04, version `0.30.10 – “Celle”`

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to achieve what you want in Linux, including Gwenview -Gthumb + Shotwell  however Gwenview has a bug that is easily got around but my particular favorite is Showfoto, which is problem free and very simple to use, all these apps are available in the software repositories.

In showfoto you just select your images in your pictures folder and open with showfoto, then go to tools-printcreator choose how many images per page and click next (the top next not the bottom one ) this lets you rotate and crop any different images, when you have gone through all the pictures click the bottom next, choose your printer, set up the printer for you page size as normal and then click print, it works perfectly.

[image]